# How do I dynamically render FB page plugin if the HTML is created after the FB JS-SDK already loaded?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have add a page widget (the formerly "likebox") on my page.

It's something like:

```
<div class="fb-page"
  data-href="https://www.facebook.com/imdb" 
  data-width="340"
  data-hide-cover="false"
  data-show-facepile="true"></div>
```

On the page. Everything works fine now.

However, I want to dynamically add extra widgets on my page after the page is loaded (including the FB js-sdk and the first widget). For example. I want to add a new Page-widget after I click a button:

```
$('button').click(function(){
  $('body').append(`
    <div class="fb-page"
      data-href="https://www.facebook.com/imdb" 
      data-width="340"
      data-hide-cover="false"
      data-show-facepile="true"></div>
  `);
})
```

But after doing so, the `div` wouldn't turn into the box.

I tried many ways like reloading the js file or removing the `FB` object. But all failed.

Is there any function like:

`FB.refillFBHTMLElements()` so that I can turn dynamically-created elements into Facebook widgets?

Comment: yes there is but it is called FB.XFBML.parse. You can even have it just check part of the page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `FB.XFBML.parse()`. I just tried it with this example, and it successfully parsed a dynamically created widget:

HTML:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous"
  src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v6.0&appId=2730175443872266&autoLogAppEvents=1"></script>

<h4>Dynamically Load Facebook Widget</h4>

<button onclick="loadWidget()" class="mb-2">Load Widget</button>

<div id="widget"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
function loadWidget() {
  const fbPage = document.createElement('div');
  fbPage.className = "fb-page";
  fbPage.dataset.href = "https://www.facebook.com/facebook";
  fbPage.dataset.tabs = "timeline";
  fbPage.dataset.width = "";
  fbPage.dataset.height = "";
  fbPage.dataset.smallHeader = "false";
  fbPage.dataset.adaptContainerWidth = "true";
  fbPage.dataset.showFacepile = "true";
  const bq = document.createElement('blockquote');
  bq.cite = "https://www.facebook.com/facebook";
  bq.className = "fb-xfbml-parse-ignore";
  const anchor = document.createElement('a');
  anchor.href = "https://www.facebook.com/facebook";
  anchor.innerHTML = 'Facebook';
  bq.appendChild(anchor);
  fbPage.appendChild(bq);
  const widget = document.getElementById('widget');
  widget.appendChild(fbPage);

  // parse the widget
  FB.XFBML.parse(widget);
}
```

Reference:

- [FB.XFBML.parse()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse)